# How can we return a refcursor as a grid in SQL Developer?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, cursor, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a package procedure that returns a REFCURSOR.
We used to be able to do the following and have the results return in a grid in SQL Developer.. but now we can't (only script output). We have no idea why! No upgrade has happened on server or clients (we've tried a few different PC's and database instances).

We used to run:

```
var rc refcursor;
exec Package.GetMasterProducts(:rc);
print rc;
```

And this would format it nicely in a grid table for us in SQL Developer.. just like running a normal `select *` and pressing `CTRL` + `Enter`.

From what I am reading, nothing on the web seems to show me that it was even possible... yet we used to do it all the time. We are running SQL Developer `4.1.3.20`.

Comment: http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2011/12/sql-developer-tip-viewing-refcursor-output/

Comment: I can do that.. but we used to get it out as a standard table like any other statement.. which all of a sudden we can no longer do.